# ¿Como ordenar los registro de una consulta Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en el cual deseo mostrar las recargas de los ususario , como puedan observar me muestra los registro que solicite , pero no me los organiza ni por id , ni por fecha y yo quisiera poder ordenar los datos por ascendentemente dependiendo de  la fecha de la recarga .

**CONTROLADOR RECARGAS**

```
public function index()
{
$usuarios = Usuario::with('recargas')->get();
return view('recargas.index' , compact('usuarios'));
}
```

**tabla donde muestro los ususarios con sus respectivas recargas**

```
<table class="table table-hover">
   <thead class="thead-dark">
      <th scope="col" >Id</th>
      <th scope="col" >Nombre</th>
      <th scope="col" >Cantida Recarga</th>
      <th scope="col" >Fecha Recarga</th>
      <th scope="col" >Acciones</th>

   </thead>
   <tbody>
      @foreach ($usuarios as $usuario)
         @foreach ($usuario->recargas as $recarga)
            <tr>
               <th scope="row"> {{$recarga->id}} </th>
               <td>  {{ $usuario->nombre . " " . $usuario->apellidos}} </td>
               <td> {{$recarga->cantidad_recarga}} </td>
               <td> {{$recarga->fecha_recarga}} </td>
               <td>             
                  <form action="{{ route('recargas.destroy' , $recarga->id) }}" method="POST">
                        <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('recargas.edit', $recarga->id) }}">  Actualizar  </a>

                        {{csrf_field()}}
                        @method('DELETE')
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Eliminar</button>
                  </form>

               </td>
            </tr>
         @endforeach
      @endforeach
   </tbody>
</table>
```

**lo que me muestra el navegador**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ordenar por la fecha de la recarga?

Comment: siii exactamente.

Comment: @NeiiderMartinezRivas solucionó su problema de ordenar los registros ? mi respuesta debería funcionar sin problemas. ;)

Comment: @Dev.Joel no he podido solucionar el problema , me los ordena por fecha , pero al parece lo hace despues que los ordena por nombre o no se como lo esta haciendo , mira mi repuesta de abajo esta una foto de como me los esta ordenando

Comment: @Dev.Joel nooo , yo las quiero ordenar por fecha , no por usuarios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si desea ordenar las recargas por su fecha, Puede hacerse añadiendo una restricción a la [Eager Loading (carga impaciente)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading) de la siguiente forma.

Para el ejemplo le decimos a Eloquent que obtenga los usuarios y sus recargas, pero que ordene las recargas por `fecha_recarga` en orden descendente. *(se pueden añadir más restricciones)*

```
$usuarios = Usuario::with(['recargas' => function($query)
{
    $query->orderBy('fecha_recarga','DESC');

}])->get();
```

Si desea ordenar las recargas indistintamente del usuario, deberá tener una relación `belongsTo()` en su modelo Recarga con su clave foránea .

```
public function usuario()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Usuario', 'usuario_id');
}
```

En su controlador obtendría los datos así. Le decimos a Eloquent que obtenga las recargas en orden descendente *(puede variar)* , pero que cada recarga incluya el usuario que la realizó.

```
$recargas = Recarga::orderBy('fecha_recarga','DESC')->with('usuario')->get();
```

Para luego en su vista, iterar los resultados , algo como este `foreach`.

```
<table>
    @foreach ($recargas as $recarga)
        <tr>
        <td>  {{ $recarga->usuario->nombre . " " . $recarga->usuario->apellidos}} </td>
            <td> {{ $recarga->cantidad_recarga}}</td>
            <td> {{ $recarga->fecha_recarga}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

Comment: me sale este error **Class 'App\Http\Controllers\App\Recarga' not found**

Comment: @NeiiderMartinezRivas donde tiene su modelo Recarga ? deberá importar dicho modelo ;)

Comment: Ya lo temgo importado

**use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Recarga;
use App\Usuario;
use Carbon\Carbon;**

Comment: @NeiiderMartinezRivas Entonces no hace falta el `App`  antes del modelo Recarga. Solo `Recarga::orderBy...` directamente. , Por qué y para importa Carbon? 3:)

Comment: listo ya me funciono , pero tengo una duda si en lugar de partir de la tabla recargas , partiera de la tabla usuarios tambien funconara? , por ejemplo ago asi ....
**$usuarios =Usuario::orderBy('fecha_recarga','DESC')->with('recargas')->get();** y obiamente en el **@foreach**  cambiando **$recargas** por **$usuarios** asi **@foreach ($usuarios as $usuario)**

discúlpame si mi pregunta es tonta o muy ignorante , pero estoy empensando con laravel y quisiera tener todo lo mas claro posible

Comment: @NeiiderMartinezRivas esa consulta daría error, ya que el modelo Usuario no tiene una columna fecha_recarga, si desea obtener las recargas indistintamente del usuario, use la segunda opción, ahora si desea que por cada usuario ordene sus recargas, use la primera. Recomiendo leer la documentación que añadí en mi respuesta y si presenta dudas o problemas no dude en generar una nueva pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: una ultima pregunta , porque se pone en el return $this->belongsTo('App\Usuario' , '**usuario_id**');  el **usuario_id**

Comment: @NeiiderMartinezRivas estás definiendo relaciones uno a muchos pero a la inversa, recomiendo leer la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships) que está entendible y con ejemplos claros.